# JSFiddle in WordPress Plugin Option Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I made a script in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JGM85/279/ and wanted to use it in my plugin option page.
I created the css file(css/style.css) and a js file(js/main.js) And I referenced it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But the datepicker is not working nor the js and css. Does Wordpress has a special way of calling JS,Jquery, and css files?

**Updated  code**

```
function super_plugin_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','super_plugin_scripts');
?>
<html>

<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select a date"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code:

```
//SETUP
function super_plugin_install(){
        //Do some installation work
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'super_plugin_install');
```

**Add Script and Style :** (Please add css and js inside your **plugin folder**)

```
//SCRIPTS
function super_plugin_scripts(){
        wp_register_style( 'my-plugincss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'css/style.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugincss' );
        wp_register_script('super_plugin_scriptjs',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/main.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('super_plugin_scriptjs');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','super_plugin_scripts');
```

Another way to add datapicker in your plugin :(not CSS, for css you need to follow above code)

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
```

Comment: for any query you can add comment.

Comment: sorry for late reply but I tried jquery-ui-core jquery-ui-datepicker since that is wat i need but still the datepicker is not working.  I updated the code above please check it. I dont understand the need of  super_plugin_install() as the plugin is already created and the is a sub menu